# Is it "allowed" or "has allowed"?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Which of the following is correct, and why?

> - Dad has allowed me to purchase a car.
> - Dad allowed me to purchase a car.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the tens­es and as­pects in English cor­re­spond tem­po­ral­ly to one an­oth­er?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tens-es-and-as-pects-in-english-cor-re-spond-tem-po-ral-ly-to-one-an)

Answer (score 0):

Using "has allowed" implies currently/ present tense, while "allowed" insinuates past tense, so you can use either, it just depends in what context you are using it. I hope this helps!